# How to run 'ls' command on directory having 400k files to find absolute path

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

```
ls -d "$PWD"/* > a.txt
```

While I'm trying to run this script this script getting timeout.

Comment: Do you need the filenames sorted (as `ls` is doing by default)?

Comment: BTW, do note [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you're making programmatic use of these names, a NUL-separated list is going to be more robust than the newline-separated list created by your command here.

Comment: @sehafoc, ...I'm assuming the OP is running this over a SSH connection or such. Though if they disabled sorting, `ls` would start emitting output as soon as it started operating.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I was guessing a python subshell hence the tag haha,  but it's hard to answer without more details

Comment: Your problem is possibly caused by shell expansion of the wildcard. Test it with `ls . > a.txt`, and then maybe find a solution which doesn't need wildcard, such as `ls . | sed_awk_perl oneliner > a.txt`.

Comment: @hyde, fair point that we'd almost certainly get a command line exceeding the legal length limit from this command (since `ls` is an external command -- the shell can expand that glob, but it can't put it onto an external command's line and successfully call `execv`). Funny that the OP is reporting a timeout, not that error.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` instead of `ls` to avoid delay for sorting:

```
find "$PWD" -depth 1 -print >files.txt
```

Even better, change your output format to be NUL-delimited, and then your output will be unambiguous even with files having surprising names (`touch $'foo\nbar'` if you want to create one of those to play with):

```
find "$PWD" -depth 1 -print0 >files.nsv
```